# GSON JsonElement to String

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having some trouble converting an JsonElement to string. I am using the getAsString() method call but i keep getting an Unsupported Operation Exception. I checked the output of the get I am calling and it seems correct.

Here is my code, Sorry for the poor naming conventions:

```
JsonParser jp2 = new JsonParser();
JsonObject root2 = jp2.parse(getAllEventsResults.get_Response()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray items2 = root2.get("items").getAsJsonArray();

for(int i=0; i<items2.size(); i++){
    JsonObject item = items2.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(item.get("start").getAsString());}
```

The weirdest part of this is that I do the same exact thing in above with this code:

```
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonObject root = jp.parse(getAllCalendarsResults.get_Response()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray items = root.get("items").getAsJsonArray();
JsonObject firstItem = items.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
String firstCalId = firstItem.get("id").getAsString();
```

Comment: are you sure that your JsonObject contains both "start" and "id", or just "id" as in second snapshot ?

Comment: I get the ID for a calendar then grab the calendar data with that id. "start" is in the events that I recieve from that calendar, when I print the JsonElement it looks like this {"dateTime":"2015-09-10T12:05:00-04:00"}. I just cant get it to convert to a string...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is it possible that `item.get("start")` is a `JsonNull`?

do check first:

```
item.get("start").isJsonNull() ? "" : item.get("start").getAsString();
```

Comment: I just ran it again to check and it isn't null, as I commented above it is returning {"dateTime":"2015-09-10T12:05:00-04:00"} just errors when i try to get it as a string.

Comment: @tallaghi do you mind posting your json string that you are working with? This way it be easier for us to help you

Comment: I was about to post the Json when I found the problem, I didnt format the Json to look at it and missed an object. Thanks for helping me point that out.

Comment: @Алексей You are my new hero of today! great reply!

Answer (score 0):

I found Gson to be very straight forward and useful for marshal and unmarshal an object into json and vice versa.

It was as simple as two helper methods..

```
/**
 * Converts an object to a Json String
 *
 * @param obj      - The object to convert to Json
 * @param dfString - data format pattern.
 * @return
 */
public static String toJson(Object obj, String dfString) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(dfString).create();
    return gson.toJson(obj);
}


/**
 * Converts a Json String to the specified Class<T>
 *
 * @param json - The Json String to covert to Class<T> instance
 * @param obj  - The Class<T> representation of the Json String
 * @return
 */
public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> obj, String dfString) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(dfString).create();
    return gson.fromJson(json, obj);
}
```

Comment: What part of the question are you answering?