# How to extract ids into a java array?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am getting below from a post request as a JSON object. (String jsonString) I am trying to extract ids into an array.

```
{"description":"studentIDs", "ids": ["123", "456", "789"]}
```

I have to extract "ids" into a java array.

I have to use com.google.gson library.

I tried below code but it gives me error.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
            
JsonArray arrJson = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("ids");
String[] arr = new String[arrJson.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < arrJson.size(); i++)
    arr[i] = arrJson.get(i);    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from JsonElement to String
```

Comment: You cannot assign a `JsonElement` into an array of `String`, since they are of different types. You need to convert it to string, which is most likely described in the documentation of the library you're using. Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521652/gson-jsonelement-to-string

Comment: Try to replace `arrJson.get(i)` by `arrJson.get(i).getAsString()` on the line where you have the type mismatch.

Comment: P.s. it's always better to create a java class which represents the answer and deserialize the answer you receive on that class. It makes the code easier to navigate and at the same time it takes out all boilerplate such as having to convert JsonElement to String explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling [`getAsString()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsString--) to get the string value from the [`JsonElement`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html):

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"description\":\"studentIDs\", \"ids\": [\"123\", \"456\", \"789\"]}";
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray arrJson = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("ids");
        String[] arr = new String[arrJson.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrJson.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = arrJson.get(i).getAsString();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Note it is likely cleaner to deserialize the JSON directly into a Java object:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.List;

class StudentIDs {
    private String description;
    private List<String> ids;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<String> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }

    public void setIds(List<String> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"description\":\"studentIDs\", \"ids\": [\"123\", \"456\", \"789\"]}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        StudentIDs studentIDs = gson.fromJson(jsonString, StudentIDs.class);
        System.out.println(studentIDs.getIds());
    }
}
```

**Output for both approaches:**

```
[123, 456, 789]
```